# How not to clear the JPA cache?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

How not to clear the JPA cache?

Code do Searching destination, poi2dicon, poi3dicon, destinationcategory with findByCode and findByName.

However, when executing the same parameter (findByCode("A")) in the for statement, the select statement is executed in the repository.

I know that the value corresponding to findByCode("A") exists in the cache of JPA.

Then, in the for statement, the query of findByCode("A") should be executed only once, but in reality, as many queries as rows.size are searched.

I wonder how to keep the value of findByCode("A") in the cache, and why the content of findByCode("A") is lost in the code now.

```
            List<Destination> result = new ArrayList<>();
            int headerLength = rows.get(0).size();
            for (int i = 1; i < rows. size(); i++) {
                Map<String, String> destinationMap = new HashMap<>();
                makeDestinaionMap(destinationMap)
                

                Destination findDestination = destinationRepository.findByCode(destinationMap.get("Identification Code"));
                Poi2dIcon poi2dIcon = poi2dIconService.findByName(destinationMap.get("2DIcon")).get(0);
                Poi3dIcon poi3dIcon = poi3dIconService.findByName(destinationMap.get("3DIcon")).get(0);
                DestinationCategory destinationCategory = destinationCategoryService.findByName(destinationMap.get("Category")).get(0);

                // builder -> save
                Destination destination = Destination.builder()
                        ...build()
                if (findDestination != null) {
                    destination.setId(findDestination.getId());
                }
                result.add(destination);
            }
            destinationRepository.saveAll(result);
```

Best Regards

Comment: Why should it use the cache? Did you enable it? Did you enable query caching and/or 2nd level caching?

Comment: @M. Deinum as far as I know, I learned that the data retrieved from the Repository is stored in the cache, but I wonder if I am misunderstanding it.

Comment: It is stored in the session but that doesn't mean the query results are cached, the query is still issues and if it happens to return the same object, it will be retrieved from the cache. But that doesn't mean that there is no query, that can only be done with a query cache (i.e. cache the query, parameters and the results thereof).